# Xcode turn off code completion for NSObject

Tags: xcode, xcode6, xcode7

Is there a way to modify Xcode's (6.4/7.x beta whatever) code completion in such a way that neither the methods nor the properties of `NSObject` in a subclass of it are shown? I think, I don't use them frequently and it is pretty annoying when searching for another function whose name I can only slightly guess and then have to scroll through all the unnessecary suggestions coming from `NSObject`.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that its possible to adjust autocomplete only for `NSObject` and descendants (of course it might be the way), but there is another nice tool I'm using:

https://github.com/FuzzyAutocomplete/FuzzyAutocompletePlugin

It won't solve a problem of unnecessary suggestions you see, but

- it's easier to add and remove from Xcode (comparing to manually internal Xcode files edit)
- it solves a problem of "searching for another function whose name
  I can only slightly guess"